# boost::filesystem::path operator/ c2296 error

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems

I am new to this boost stuff and had a small doubt regarding boost::filesystem::path.
I have an application which uses a relative path of a config file needed to start this application.
I currently use:

```
boost::filesystem::path PATH(".\\..\\dir1\\file1.xml");
```

I looked at the / operator of boost::filesystem::path and was interested in using that.

I tried this:

```
boost::filesystem::path const PATH("."/"dir1"/"file1.xml");
```

but got an error
: error C2296: '/' : illegal, left operand has type 'const char [2]'
: error C2297: '/' : illegal, right operand has type 'const char [5]'

It their a clean way to use it?

How can I use the / operator to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one operand of `/` must already be a path, try:

```
boost::filesystem::path const PATH(boost::filesystem::path(".")/"dir1"/"file1.xml");
```

or if C++11 is allowed, simplify it to:

```
const auto PATH = boost::filesystem::path(".")/"dir1"/"file1.xml";
```

Comment: @DeeptiJain Are you sure? Even if there is an error, it can't be the *same* error message as the left-hand-side is no longer `const char[2]`.

Comment: Aah.. my bad. It works. I forgot to save the file before building the project. Thanks